# Why am I not able to log to rsyslog?

Tags: 9, log-messages

I am trying to use System Logging on a Drupal 9.5 site running on CentOS7. I have followed the guide from here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/core/modules/syslog/overview and have the following set up:

1. in /etc/rsyslog.d/drupal.conf

   if $programname startswith 'drupal' then {

   action(type="omfile" File="/var/log/drupal.log")

   stop
   }
2. at the end of /etc/rsyslog.conf

   local3.*     /var/log/drupal.log
3. in Drupal's Syslog settings set "Syslog identity" to LOG_LOCAL3

I then restarted rsyslog and verified with systemctl status rsyslog that it was active.

There is never a /var/log/drupal.log file created and there are no Drupal messages dumped to /var/log/messages.